# Splitting a String using 2 Characters

Tags: arrays, string, vb.net, split, char

I'm currently splitting on periods in my code, but found a few issues when I ran it. I was wondering how I could split on ". " instead of just "."

Current Code:

```
Dim words As String() = item.Split(New Char() {"."c})
```

Dream Code:

```
Dim words As String() = item.Split(New Char() {". "c})
```

It doesn't allow me to add that extra space in after the period, is there a workaround?

Comment: It doesnt allow it because a char array holds characters not 2 character strings.  One way is to replace with something unlikely to be in the string like `|` then split on that.  Please stop putting language tags in the title - that is what the tags are for

Comment: @Plutonix could you elaborate a little?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on that, see how `Replace` is used first? First you turn the 2 characters into one that is going to be uniquely identifiable, and then you can split it effectively.

```
Dim words As String() = item.Replace(". ", "|").Split(New Char() {"|"c})
```

And you can probably simplify it even more like this:

```
Dim words As String() = item.Replace(". ", "|").Split("|"c)
```

That assumes you are using `Option Strict On` - if not, you can simplify it more like this as the string will be converted to a char automatically:

```
Dim words As String() = item.Replace(". ", "|").Split("|")
```

Comment: Ahh ok that's what I thought he was talking about. I wrote it out on two lines, but your one liner is just oh so pretty. Thank yoU!

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [String.Split Method (String(), StringSplitOptions)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) overload of String.Split:

```
Dim s = "1. 2. 3. 4.5.6"
Dim a = s.Split({". "}, StringSplitOptions.None)
Console.Write(String.Join(vbCrLf, a))
```

outputs:

```
1
2
3
4.5.6
```

(Depending on the version of Visual Studio, you might need something like `New String() {". "}` instead of `{". "}`.)